# Array and Object Problems Vue

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Hi this is my first post on here so be kind, Im new to vue and cant seem to get this to work and its slowly driving me nuts! I have a large array of data and cherry picking what i want into a table. The last col of the table is a drop down menu of reports. Now in current year reports the data is listed as so:- (I've removed a lot of data to shorten it)

```
...
        "reports": {
          "reports_entry": {
            "report_title": "Tournament Entries",
            "report_url": "some url"
          }
        }
      },
```

In Previous years its as follows:-

```
...
   reports": {
    "reports_entry": [
      {
        "report_title": "Tournament Entries",
        "report_url": "https://alps.ocs-ffg.com/tic/tmentry.cgi?tourn=QS19~season=2019~alphaorder~"
      },
      {
        "report_title": "Round 1 Draw",
        "report_url": "Some Url"
      },
      {
        "report_title": "Round 1 Scores Only",
        "report_url": "Some Url"
      },
      {
        "report_title": "Round 2 Draw",
        "report_url": "Some Url"
      },
      {
        "report_title": "Round 2 Scores Only",
        "report_url": "Some Url"
      },
      {
        "report_title": "Round 2 Scoreboard",
        "report_url": "Some Url"
      },
      {
        "report_title": "Final Result",
        "report_url": "Some Url"
      },
      {
        "report_title": "Scoring Statistics",
        "report_url": "Some Url"
      },
      {
        "report_title": "Course Statistics",
        "report_url": "Some Url"
      }
    ]
  },
```

When i display the dropdown menu i can either get this year working but not previous or the other way around I know the problem is with the v-if being and array or object and tried so many different ways and nothing is working please help! my code :-

```
<template>
  <b-card-body class="text-center">
    <b-table :items="data" :fields="fields">
      <template #cell(reports)="row">
        <b-nav card-header pills>
          <b-dropdown v-if="!row.item.reports.length === null " text="report">
            <b-dropdown-item
              v-for="reports in row.item.reports"
              :key="reports"
              :title="reports"
              >{{ reports.report_title }}</b-dropdown-item
            >
          </b-dropdown>
          <b-dropdown v-else text="report">
            <b-dropdown-item
              v-for="reports in row.item.reports.reports_entry"
              :key="reports"
              :title="reports"
              >{{ reports.report_title }}</b-dropdown-item
            >
          </b-dropdown>
        </b-nav>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </b-card-body>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "scheduleTable",
  props: ["id", "fields", "data", "currentSeason"],
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted the problem using Array.isArray(row.item.reports.reports_entry)